# ¿Cómo enviar archivo pdf rellenable desde la pàgina web?

Tags: html, web, pdf, contact-form-7

Quisiera saber cómo puedo colocar en la página web que estoy diseñando, un formulario en pdf, que cuando el usuario lo llene, se guarde y lo envíe al correo señalado.

Comment: Vale, no  has buscado siquiera si existe, algo. Ese no es el espíritu que quiere promover stackoverflow con respecto a la programación, primero busca, después intenta algo, y cuando ya veas que no eres capaz, publica una [pregunta de calidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Si quieres empezar a buscar en algún [sitio mira este enlace](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/send-pdf-for-contact-form-7/), el cual he encontrado simplemente buscando en google "contact-form PDF" y ha salido como primera opción. Esta pregunta no merece una respuesta mejor :(

Comment: @enrique manzano gil claro que he buscado, sino no preguntara acá, antes de hacer un comentario asi, busca mis otras preguntas para que veas. Pero no te preocupes

Comment: No me refiero a las otras preguntas, me refiero a esta, preguntas que si hay alguna forma de rellenar un formulario pdf y enviarlo a un mail con `contact-form-7`... Solo poniendolo en el buscador ya la primera sugerencia de google te responde a la pregunta que has hecho... No necesito ver las otras preguntas para analizar esta, esta pregunta es la que está mal formulada, si has buscado, pon siempre hasta donde has llegado y qué problemas te has encontrado en el proceso, ten en cuenta que es una web para AYUDAR incluso preguntando, para futuras personas con ese mismo problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Te puedo dar una idea**. Puedes crear un **formulario** por tu parte, luego obtener esos datos con **JavaScript** y usar esta librería http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted, para eso debes descargar los siguientes scripts: **pdfmake.min.js** y **vfs_fonts.js**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='pdfmake.min.js'></script>
<script src='vfs_fonts.js'></script>
<script>
    function onPDF(){
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
        var docDefinition = { content: "Mi nombre es : " + nombre + " y mi apellido es: " + apellido};
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open(); //Abrir PDF
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).print(); //Imprimir PDF
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('Persona.pdf'); //Descargar PDF
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Nombres:<br>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" value="">
    <br>
    Apellido:<br>
    <input type="text" id="apellido" value="">
    <br><br>
</form> 

<input type="Button" value="Abrir PDF" onClick="onPDF()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cómo añado la opción de enviarlo al correo del webmaster?